# How to set base url and query parameters for WebClient?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

In my service, I have to get response from some different urls with parameters.

1. get from http://a.com:8080/path1?param1=v1
2. get from http://b.com:8080/path2?param2=v2
3. get from http://c.com:8080/path3?param3=v3

I am using WebClient to do the job as following.

```
public class WebClientTest {
    private WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().build();

    @Test
    public void webClientTest() {
        Mono<String> a = webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.scheme("http").host("a.com").port(8080).path("/path1")
                    .queryParam("param1", "v1")
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

        Mono<String> b = webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.scheme("http").host("b.com").port(8080).path("/path2")
                    .queryParam("param2", "v2")
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

        Mono<String> c = webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.scheme("http").host("c.com").port(8080).path("/path3")
                    .queryParam("param3", "v3")
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);

        //zip the result
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have to set scheme, host, port separately again and again.
So my questions are:
1. Am I using WebClient in a right way?
2. Is it possible to set scheme, host, port in a method together? I know that `webClient.get().uri("http://a.com:8080/path1?param1=v1").retrieve()` works, but what I am expecting is something like:

```
    webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder/*.url("http://a.com:8080/path1")*/
                    .queryParam("param1", "v1")
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As of Spring Framework 5.2, there is an additional method that can help with your specific situation:

```
Mono<String> response = this.webClient
    .get()
    .uri("http://a.com:8080/path1", uri -> uri.queryParam("param1", "v1").build())
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class);
```

I wouldn't advise creating one `WebClient` per host as a general rule. It really depends on your use case. Here it seems your client might send requests to many hosts, and creating many HTTP clients can be a bit wasteful here.

Comment: This worked for me. For anyone who was trying to use `.uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path().queryParam( ... ) )` it might not work if there is a Bean configured in WebClientConfiguration with a baseUrl. That baseUrl will be prepended to your request.

Comment: Saved my life, didn't know `uri` has this method.

Answer (score -1):

The way I solved this was to have a WebClient for each different url.

So you would have

```
   private WebClient aClient = WebClient.create("a.com")
   private WebClient bClient = WebClient.create("b.com")
   private WebClient cClient = WebClient.create("c.com")
```

Then interact with each WebClient depending on what you're calling.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve